# Prove using squared number property

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

$$ If \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i=10 $$ Prove that $$ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i^2\ge 10 $$

Comment: Can you prove this for $2$ terms in each sum?

Comment: For x being interger (+ve, -ve, or non-negative) x^2 is always >= x, so, the property holds in this case. but what if x is non-integer?

Answer (score 2):

Use the AM-GM.

For $n=2$ :
$$x_1+x_2=10 \Rightarrow x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2=100\le 2(x_1^2+x_2^2) \Rightarrow x_1^2+x_2^2\ge \frac{100}{2}.$$
Similarly, for any $n$:
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n=10 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}x_ix_j=100\le n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2 \Rightarrow \\\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\ge \frac{100}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}1^2\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i^2\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i\right)^2=100.$$
Id est, $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i^2\geq10$$ and we are done!

Also, we can use the Tangent Line method:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i^2-10=\sum_{i=1}^{10}(x_i^2-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}(x_i^2-1-2(x_i-1))=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{10}(x_i^2-2x_i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}(x_i-1)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for each $i$ we have $$x_i^2\geq 2x_i-1$$
and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

By RMS-AM,
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac1{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i^2\right)^{\frac12}&\geq\frac1{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i=1\\
\sum_{i=1}^{10}x_i^2&\geq10
\end{align}$$